# Using sed to change all contents of a file except a particular line number (the header)?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I want to use sed on Linux to change all the second fields in a CSV file for all rows *except* the first row (which is the header). I'm aware that I can just loop this and go line by line using sed -i '{$LINE_NUMBER ....' and not using this on that line, but I'm wondering if there is a way to do this without a loop which is slower.

I guess I could also just change all contents. Then in the next line change it back for this one particular line.

```
| Q1 | Q2 | Q3 |
| Name    | Resource_ID | Key |
| Joseph | 343433| AGFD |
| Mary | 242355 | AREW |
```

Comment: What file? How can we help you parse a file if you don't show it? Please [edit] your question and add an example of your file and the output you want to see from it. It's unlikely that `sed` will be the best tool for the job if you are working with fields, but we can't know without seeing the data.

Comment: @terdon I just updated the question.

Comment: You posted half of an example, the sample input. Please [edit] your question to show us the other half, i.e. the expected output. Also, sed may be completely inappropriate for whatever it is you're trying to do so if you tell/show us that too we can better help you come up with a good solution.

Answer (score 4):

We can't give you a definitive answer without seeing your data, but from what you describe, you're looking for `2,${}`. For example:

```
$ seq 5 | sed '2,${s/$/foo/}'
1
2foo
3foo
4foo
5foo
```

That means run the code in `{}` from the 2nd line until the end of the file. But chances are you'd be better off using `awk` or any other tool that can natively handle "fields".

Comment: alternatively, `seq 5 | sed '1n;s/$/foo/'`.  but yeah, when working with columns/fields, awk or perl (or miller or datamash or lots of other tools) are a better choice than sed.

Answer (score -1):

Awk is almost certainly a better choice than sed for what you're trying to do. I'm guessing that when you say you want to modify the 2nd field, it's actually the 3rd `|`-separated field you're referring to in which case:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} NR>1{$3=" whatever "} 1' file
| Q1 | Q2 | Q3 |
| Name    | whatever | Key |
| Joseph | whatever | AGFD |
| Mary | whatever | AREW |
```